# How to write unit test for Threads with mockK

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockk

I want to write unit test for below function using mockK library:

```
void function_name() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //some code
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I tried using Thread provided in mockk:

```
@Test
fun function_name() {
    val bundle = spyk()

    Thread {
        Thread.sleep(4000)
        presenter.navigateToScreen(bundle)
    }.start()

    verify(timeout = 5000){
        //to verify statement
    }
}
```

But test fails to verify provided in verify block.

How to test above function which contains delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't quite complete enough to make it clear what you're trying to do, but it seems that your test:

1. Starts a thread that sleeps for 4 seconds, then calls `presenter.navigateToScreen()`.
2. While that thread is still sleeping, you have a verify allowing 5 seconds for some conditions to be fulfilled
3. During the verify, the first thread will complete its 4 second sleep - with 1 second of verify left - and call `presenter.navigateToScreen()` which will presumably call your `function_call()` method.
4. Your `function_call()` method - with at most 1 second of `verify{}` left - will sleep for 4 seconds, exhausting `verify{}`'s patience, and then run `// Some code`.
5. Since the `verify{}` is presumably testing something done in `// Some code`, which runs 3 seconds after the `verify{}` is complete, it will never verify.

So you want to remove the Sleep from your test's code. If your intention is to ensure that the sleep(4000) is called, consider mocking it, as I mention below.

Notes:

1. When I'm testing threads - if I can - I move the code executed by the thread into a different method or class, so I can test the logic independently from the thread handling.
2. When I'm testing things like `Thread.sleep()` (or `Instant.now()`), I inject methods and mock them or validate them as appropriate. This means that tests don't need to wait for any real time at all: the code under test just has to believe whatever the mocked `sleep()` or `now()` conspire to make them believe.

(I also think it's funny to have helper global things called 'timeMachine' and 'sleepMachine', although they're really factories, I suppose: it saves typing `{ millis -> Thread.sleep(millis) }` multiple times.)

Block quote because the code thing doesn't like my Kotlin:

> ```
> fun trySeveral(
>     tries: Int,
>     sleepMs: (Long) -> Unit = { millis -> Thread.sleep(millis) },
>     now: () -> Instant = { Instant.now() }
> ): Duration? {
>   repeat(tries) {
>     try {
>       val started = now()
>       // some code that throws or doesn't throw
>       return Duration.between(started, now())
>     } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
>       logger("Failed attempt $it ", e)
>     }
>     sleepMs(200) // Some logic to avoid final sleep
>   }
>   return null
> }
> ```

Here, I can test the function by mocking `now()` and/or validating `sleep()`, depending on whether the commented out section above throws or doesn't:

> ```
> val sleepMs = mockk<(Long) -> Unit>(relaxed = true)
> val now = mockk<() -> Instant>()
> every { now() } returnsMany listOf(1,2,3).map { Instant.ofEpochSecond(it) }
>
> trySeveral(3, sleepMs, now) 
>
> verify(exactly = 2) {  // TODO: skip the final sleep
>    sleepMs(200)
> }
> ```

You can also mock statics, but I don't like that because <mumble mumble global scope mumble>:

> ```
> mockkStatic(Thread::class)
> every { Thread.sleep(any()) } just Runs
> ```